# How to Add PopupMenu in manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, popup

```
Manipulate[Column[{ Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}], Plot[Cos[a y], {y, 0, 2*Pi}], Plot[Tan[a z], {z, 0, 3*Pi}]}], {a, 1, 10}]
```

I want to put a popup menu here as  Sin, Cos & Tan. So I can only display which plot want to display. Please help to do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[[1]][a x], {x, 0, f[[2]] Pi}],
  {a, 1, 10}, 
  {{f, {Sin, 1}}, {{Sin, 1} -> Sin, {Cos, 2} -> Cos, {Tan, 3} -> Tan}, PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[a x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}
  ],
 {{f, Sin}, {Sin, Cos, Tan}},
 {a, 1, 10}
 , ControlType -> {PopupMenu, Slider}
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

A slight variation on kglr's answer to track the original variable names.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{
   func = {Sin, Cos, Tan}[[n]],
   var = {x, y, z}[[n]]},
  Plot[func[a*t], {t, 0, n*Pi},
   PlotRange -> If[n == 3, {-7, 7}, {-1, 1}],
   AxesLabel -> {var, func["a"*var]}]],
 {{a, 2}, 1, 10, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{n, 1, "function"}, Thread[Range[3] -> {Sin, Cos, Tan}], PopupMenu}]
```

[image]